# VSE: Clip with different aspect ratio, speed up and transformed

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I would like to import a 1920x1080 video into a clip that is rendered at a different aspect ratio, e.g. 800x800.

If I add the movie clip it is automatically scaled to 800x800 - which can be changed by setting the Offset of the clip.

It is also possible to add a speed transform to this clip or to add a transform effect to move the viewport (e.g. to only look at the left half of the original clip).

When adding a transform effect on top of the speed effect the image gets distorted again.

Do I have to set Offset for the transform, the speed effect and/or the original clip?

Thanks, Oliver